# MYSQL LEFT JOIN not showing Null Rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. amenities_posts containing all available amenities and properties_amenities containing only a properties amenities.
I would like to run a join query that will return all rows from amenities_posts with NULL if a row is not found in properties_amenities.

Current Query:

```
SELECT properties_amenities.*, amenities_posts.type, amenities_posts.grouped, amenities_posts.title, properties_amenities.property_id 
FROM properties_amenities 
LEFT JOIN amenities_posts ON properties_amenities.amenity_id = amenities_posts.id
WHERE properties_amenities.property_id=318 OR properties_amenities.property_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY amenities_posts.grouped DESC, amenities_posts.sortby ASC;
```

This query only returns rows from `properties_amenities` and not all amenities rows with nulls.

Comment: it would be better if you could share your table structure.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: I'm new to stack exchange, so what is the best way to post structure and sample data?
Can I attach SQL files to post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show all rows from amenities_posts, it needs to go on the *left* side of the LEFT JOIN.

```
...
FROM amenities_posts
LEFT JOIN properties_amenities ...
```

A left join selects all rows from the left side, and only matching rows from the right side.

Comment: Can you show the complete query you are suggesting based on my current query?

Comment: All I'm suggesting is switching the two tables to the opposite side of the join. The rest of it looks fine, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi,
I tried switching the tables, but the results still did not show all rows amenities_posts, but only rows from properties_amenities  where there were matching records from on clause. (properties_amenities.amenity_id = amenities_posts.id)
I have solved the problem another way.
Thanks for your help.